# What is the meaning of Scalar(0,0,0,)?

Tags: c++, opencv

Hello i want to ask what is this line of code do?

```
Mat res(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0,0,0));
```

i'm guessing it's making matrix of image rows and columns but i still don't understand what's the Scalar(0,0,0) for?

Comment: Scalar can be interpreted as a color here, in this case it's RGB(0,0,0). But since the type is `8UC1`, only the first value of the scalar is actually read.

Comment: cv::Scalar is typically used for variables in functions that support different number of dimensions. If you font know the number but want to set for example every dimension to zero, just use: cv::Scalar::all(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html), you are using the fourth constructor:

```
Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, const Scalar &s);
```

The third argument is the array type for the elements of the matrix. You are using CV_8UC1: 8-bit **single-channel** array.

The fourth argument is an optional value to initialize each matrix element with. Scalar is simmilar to a 4x1 vector. However, since you have specified a single channel, only the first value will be copied to the matrix elements. If you had specified more channels, the remaining elements of Scalar would be used.